# Identify the technologies use to create this architecture

Tags: php, apache, http

I’ve been using stackoverflow for a while and this is my first post.
I’ve been trying to figure out how to create a system that works like this and haven’t arrive at the solution that I want. So I have a situation like this: I have computer a and computer b behind a router that is connected to the internet. Both a and b are connected to the same router and are on the same subnet. Computer a runs an apache httpd service on port 80, and the router is configured to forward http request on port 80 to computer a. Computer a host a website that contains a list of files. Computer b contains the files that are listed on a’s website. B have access to the internet but does not have any open port for inbound request configured on the router. Both a and b can see each other by being on the same subnet. What I would like to happen is when the user click on a file on a, a invokes b to send the requested file to the user but without sending the file back to a. How do I accomplish this?

Things that I have investigated so far are Apache load Balancer, and proxying, where b stands in the middle between the user and computer a and capture traffics as a responds to user requests. But I kinda feel this is a clumsy approach. I’m interested in hearing more simple and robust solutions to approach this problem.

Thank you
Tam

Answer (score 0):

You should raise two servers in each computer, then the proxy will route to any of them. The solution will be easier this way,.

Comment: I only need b to respond to a’s request on where to send the large file back on a’s behalf. For all other web access operations can be handled by a itself. Traffic from b cannot go through a.